# async_connect blocks io_service::run_one() in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to run following code:

```
some_sock.async_connect(...); // handle_connect() sets the 'condition' flag

boost::asio::deadline_timer t(ios, boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
while (t.expires_from_now() >= boost::posix_time::seconds(0))
{
  ios.run_one();
  if (condition) return;
}
```

Desirable behavior is return from run_one() after timer t is expired (after 2 seconds).
Actually, run_one() blocks until SYN-ACK or RST is received. If the server is not responding, run_one() will block for a much longer timeout than 2 seconds.

What should I do to wait specified amount of time for connect doing some work in background?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. t.async_wait(boost::bind(empty_function())); solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `io_service::run` and `deadline_timer::async_wait` as described in the [async tcp client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Call run_one() for connect() in another thread. On timeout call some_sock.cancel(). (Read its documentation first).